# Routing with an Allied Telesis switch and ARP bottleneck

Tags: routing, arp, bottleneck

I use an Allied Telesis x610/24-Ts switch as a central switch in a company building. The central switch connects several edge switches and also provides routing between VLANs.

The forwarding capability of this router is specified at 70 Mpps, but when the router forwards packets from vlan1 to vlan2 to disabled or non-existent host, even 200 packets per second can block any forwarding to vlan2. The problem is that the vlan2 side is trying to resolve MAC address via ARP queries, there are many packets in the queue, almost all to a host that is not responding and no other ARP will be served during this time.

Is there any way to remedy this behavior? I imagine that such unanswered ARP queries should be negatively cached, so as not to block potential other queries. Another solution could be to increase the number of parallel queries. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

> The forwarding capability of this router is specified at 70 Mpps

For a layer-3 switch that is very poor - sounds like routing between VLANs is implemented in software. A decent L3 switch routes at "wire speed" - as fast as it switches.

> when the router forwards packets from vlan1 to vlan2 to disabled or non-existent host, even 200 packets per second can block any forwarding to vlan2.

Even worse.

I'd replace the switch right away. Please understand that we can't recommend products or vendors here.